# How to Check, What is the unreadable content in excel sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, phpexcel

I am working on creating excel sheet using PHP Excel. Excel sheet is creating fine and there are no errors while creating excel sheet. This excel sheet has some formulas on few columns as well as some cells has dropdown list (values for these list are saved in seperate tab).

Now, When I open this sheet, then MS Excel is showing me message that:
**Excel found unreadable content in abc.xlsx. Do you want it to recorver?**

After click **YES** button, MS Excel shows me another dialog box in which it describes the recover process. Please check the below screenshot of that 2nd dialog box.

[image]

After recovering excel sheet is opened. But I am not able to get what was unreadable or corrupted content into this sheet so that I can fix it.

Below is simple code to create and then download excel sheet nothing else:

```
$excelname = 'Testing';
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $excelname . ' Template.xlsx"');
$objWriter2 = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter2->save('php://output');
```

With the above code, I am still getting the first message that:  **Excel found unreadable content in abc.xlsx. Do you want it to recorver?**  Now, I am very confused about what is wrong into above line of code.

Can anyone please tell me, How can I find what was unreadable or corrupted content into excel sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't that log file tell you anything?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..The log file is saying the same thing, which is showing in the dialog box

Comment: Well the only thing that message tells me is that there's a named range defined in the spreadsheet that isn't valid.... so I'd suggest checking all the named ranges in the spreadsheet and removing any that aren't actually used, or possibly converting any that reference  single cell (e.g. `B2`) to an actual range value (`B2:B2`)

Comment: I have edited my post and added my script to just only create excel sheet and then download. But still getting the same issue.

Comment: The code that you've posted creates a blank worksheet.... that will not give unreadable content for named ranges

Comment: Yes I know. I am just test the the code after removing all the code and trying to create and then download excel. But issue/error is same. And I don't know what is the problem with these few line of codes?

Answer (score 0):

looks like a hardware issue. Create a backup of the disk you are using and consult your IT dpt specialists.

Comment: experience brother... hardtime experience))

Comment: I'm asking for a proof / explanation / solution.  Not your experience level.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys...Please again look at my code to create and then download excel sheet.